# Kubernetes Pod stuck in container creating

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kompose

I am trying to deploy this `docker-compose` app on GCP kubernetes.

```yaml
version: "3.5"

x-environment:
  &default-back-environment
  # Database settings
  POSTGRES_DB: taiga
  POSTGRES_USER: taiga
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: taiga
  POSTGRES_HOST: taiga-db
  # Taiga settings
  TAIGA_SECRET_KEY: "taiga-back-secret-key"
  TAIGA_SITES_SCHEME: "http"
  TAIGA_SITES_DOMAIN: "localhost:9000"
  TAIGA_SUBPATH: "" # "" or "/subpath"
  # Email settings. Uncomment following lines and configure your SMTP server
  # EMAIL_BACKEND: "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
  # DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL: "no-reply@example.com"
  # EMAIL_USE_TLS: "False"
  # EMAIL_USE_SSL: "False"
  # EMAIL_HOST: "smtp.host.example.com"
  # EMAIL_PORT: 587
  # EMAIL_HOST_USER: "user"
  # EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD: "password"
  # Rabbitmq settings
  # Should be the same as in taiga-async-rabbitmq and taiga-events-rabbitmq
  RABBITMQ_USER: taiga
  RABBITMQ_PASS: taiga
  # Telemetry settings
  ENABLE_TELEMETRY: "True"

x-volumes:
  &default-back-volumes
  - taiga-static-data:/taiga-back/static
  - taiga-media-data:/taiga-back/media
  # - ./config.py:/taiga-back/settings/config.py


services:
  taiga-db:
    image: postgres:12.3
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: taiga
      POSTGRES_USER: taiga
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: taiga
    volumes:
      - taiga-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - taiga

  taiga-back:
    image: taigaio/taiga-back:latest
    environment: *default-back-environment
    volumes: *default-back-volumes
    networks:
      - taiga
    depends_on:
      - taiga-db
      - taiga-events-rabbitmq
      - taiga-async-rabbitmq

  taiga-async:
    image: taigaio/taiga-back:latest
    entrypoint: ["/taiga-back/docker/async_entrypoint.sh"]
    environment: *default-back-environment
    volumes: *default-back-volumes
    networks:
      - taiga
    depends_on:
      - taiga-db
      - taiga-back
      - taiga-async-rabbitmq

  taiga-async-rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8-management-alpine
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE: secret-erlang-cookie
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: taiga
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: taiga
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: taiga
    volumes:
      - taiga-async-rabbitmq-data:/var/lib/rabbitmq
    networks:
      - taiga

  taiga-front:
    image: taigaio/taiga-front:latest
    environment:
      TAIGA_URL: "http://localhost:9000"
      TAIGA_WEBSOCKETS_URL: "ws://localhost:9000"
      TAIGA_SUBPATH: "" # "" or "/subpath"
    networks:
      - taiga
    # volumes:
    #   - ./conf.json:/usr/share/nginx/html/conf.json

  taiga-events:
    image: taigaio/taiga-events:latest
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_USER: taiga
      RABBITMQ_PASS: taiga
      TAIGA_SECRET_KEY: "taiga-back-secret-key"
    networks:
      - taiga
    depends_on:
      - taiga-events-rabbitmq

  taiga-events-rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8-management-alpine
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE: secret-erlang-cookie
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: taiga
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: taiga
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: taiga
    volumes:
      - taiga-events-rabbitmq-data:/var/lib/rabbitmq
    networks:
      - taiga

  taiga-protected:
    image: taigaio/taiga-protected:latest
    environment:
      MAX_AGE: 360
      SECRET_KEY: "taiga-back-secret-key"
    networks:
      - taiga

  taiga-gateway:
    image: nginx:1.19-alpine
    ports:
      - "9000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./taiga-gateway/taiga.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - taiga-static-data:/taiga/static
      - taiga-media-data:/taiga/media
    networks:
      - taiga
    depends_on:
      - taiga-front
      - taiga-back
      - taiga-events

volumes:
  taiga-static-data:
  taiga-media-data:
  taiga-db-data:
  taiga-async-rabbitmq-data:
  taiga-events-rabbitmq-data:

networks:
  taiga:
```

I have used `Kompose` to generate my kubernetes deployment files. All the pods are running bare two. However, they show no error except this.

> Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted
> volumes=[taiga-static-data taiga-media-data], unattached
> volumes=[kube-api-access-9c74v taiga-gateway-claim0 taiga-static-data
> taiga-media-data]: timed out waiting for the condition

Pod Status

```
taiga-async-6c7d9dbd7b-btv79             1/1     Running             19         16h
taiga-async-rabbitmq-86979cf759-lvj2m    1/1     Running             0          16h
taiga-back-7bc574768d-hst2v              0/1     ContainerCreating   0          6m34s
taiga-db-59b554854-qdb65                 1/1     Running             0          16h
taiga-events-74f494df97-8rpjd            1/1     Running             0          16h
taiga-events-rabbitmq-7f558ddf88-wc2js   1/1     Running             0          16h
taiga-front-6f66c475df-8cmf6             1/1     Running             0          16h
taiga-gateway-77976dc77-w5hp4            0/1     ContainerCreating   0          3m6s
taiga-protected-7794949d49-crgbt         1/1     Running             0          16h
```

It is a problem with mounting the volume, I am certain as it seems from an earlier error that `taiga-back` and `taiga-db` share a volume.

This is the `Kompose` file I have.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml
    kompose.version: 1.26.1 (a9d05d509)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: taiga-gateway
  name: taiga-gateway
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: taiga-gateway
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml
        kompose.version: 1.26.1 (a9d05d509)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.network/taiga: "true"
        io.kompose.service: taiga-gateway
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: nginx:1.19-alpine
          name: taiga-gateway
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
              
              name: taiga-gateway-claim0
            - mountPath: /taiga/static
              name: taiga-static-data
              
            - mountPath: /taiga/media
              name: taiga-media-data
              
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: taiga-gateway-claim0
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: taiga-gateway-claim0
        - name: taiga-static-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: taiga-static-data
        - name: taiga-media-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: taiga-media-data
status: {}
```

Perhaps if I can fix one I can figure out the other pod as well. This is the application
https://github.com/kaleidos-ventures/taiga-docker . Any pointers are welcome. `kubectl describe pod` output

```
Name:           taiga-gateway-77976dc77-w5hp4
Namespace:      default
Priority:       0
Node:           gke-taiga-cluster-default-pool-9e5ed1f4-0hln/10.128.0.18
Start Time:     Wed, 13 Apr 2022 05:32:10 +0000
Labels:         io.kompose.network/taiga=true
                io.kompose.service=taiga-gateway
                pod-template-hash=77976dc77
Annotations:    kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml
                kompose.version: 1.26.1 (a9d05d509)
Status:         Pending
IP:
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/taiga-gateway-77976dc77
Containers:
  taiga-gateway:
    Container ID:
    Image:          nginx:1.19-alpine
    Image ID:
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf from taiga-gateway-claim0 (rw)
      /taiga/media from taiga-media-data (rw)
      /taiga/static from taiga-static-data (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-9c74v (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  taiga-gateway-claim0:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  taiga-gateway-claim0
    ReadOnly:   false
  taiga-static-data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  taiga-static-data
    ReadOnly:   false
  taiga-media-data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  taiga-media-data
    ReadOnly:   false
  kube-api-access-9c74v:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------       ----                 ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled    16m                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/taiga-gateway-77976dc77-w5hp4 to gke-taiga-cluster-default-pool-9e5ed1f4-0hln
  Warning  FailedMount  5m49s (x4 over 14m)  kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[taiga-static-data taiga-media-data], unattached volumes=[taiga-gateway-claim0 taiga-static-data taiga-media-data kube-api-access-9c74v]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  81s (x3 over 10m)    kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[taiga-static-data taiga-media-data], unattached volumes=[kube-api-access-9c74v taiga-gateway-claim0 taiga-static-data taiga-media-data]: timed out waiting for the condition
```

Comment: can you describe that pod and share the output

Comment: Is this a self-managed k8s cluster, or you are using managed cluster like GKE, EKS?

Comment: @gohm'c GCP..I mentioned it in the question. I need to write a different yaml for creating Volumes? Kompose doesn't take care of that?

Comment: No. Checkout the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
volumes:
  taiga-static-data:
  taiga-media-data:
  taiga-db-data:
  taiga-async-rabbitmq-data:
  taiga-events-rabbitmq-data:
```

Base on your origin docker spec you can replace `persistentVolumeClaim` with `emptyDir`.

```
volumes:
- name: taiga-gateway-claim0
  emptyDir: {}
- name: taiga-static-data
  emptyDir: {}
- name: taiga-media-data
  emptyDir: {}
```

Or if you want to persist your data (continue using `persistentVolumeClaim`), you should create the PVC first:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: taiga-gateway-claim0
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: taiga-static-data
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: taiga-media-data
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  ...
```

The above spec will dynamically provision 3 persistent volumes for your pod using the default StorageClass on your **GKE** cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have not configured your PVCs right and the container is trying to mount the claim, but the claim is not bound to a PV.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that taiga-static-data & taiga-media-data pvcs are bound to their respective pvs.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the persistent volumes are not bound to the pod hence the pod is failed to start. Ensure the storage is configured and the persistent volumes are created.

Comment: Any example of "configuring storgae" in this case you can point to?

Comment: use nfs storage and create pv's. ensure tyhe pvc's are bound to the respective pv. or use ephemeral storage to start the pod